# Classic ADO.Recordset Alternative in ADO.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

As from title you can guess that I am old developer.
I was using ADO with VB 6.0. now adopting VB.NET with ADO.NET with Access database (small application)

To the point I am facing problem in data writing to database.
In old technology of ADO I am able to Read data from field to control by looping controls with same name as field.

Same I was able to write controls value back to fields (add or edit) to save data using ADO.Recordset.AddNew method and ADO.RecordSet.Update method. that was so simple.

But in ADO.NET

DataReader = limited to read only Data, forward only cannot use to move in result. cannot update.

DataSet = Not getting how to update record without SQL Update command (using loop of control and its value)
Dataset,DataAdapter,DataTable makes much complex coding than Classic ADO classic

I tried there is dataAdapter.updatecommand(updatecmd,conn) but i don't have update SQL at all

can anyone guide me how to save data back to fields using control name and its value, using DataSet, Data Adapter, DataTable.

I searched about 2 days but failed to get straight solution they are not as per my need. I want to make general read / write functionality for whole project, not for specific form or specific table.

and again I have doubt that is ADO.Net is advancement to classic ADO

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show us your adapted code,but Microsoft has a good documentation in that regard

Comment: There are a variety of ways to _Select_, _Insert_, and _Update_ when using an Access database. See the following [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview), [OLE DB Programming Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/oledb/ole-db-programming-overview?view=msvc-170) and [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). There are even third-party libraries such as [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper#supportedframeworks-body-tab).

Comment: _Entity Framework_ may also work.

Comment: _they are not as per my need_: You need to determine the difference between _what you need_ versus _what you want_. Once you resolve that you may find your solution. _Security_ is on the forefront of mind these days to prevent things such as _sql injection_. The _old way_ of doing things such as leaving one's front door unlocked when going to bed at night and  leaving the keys to one's car in the ignition just aren't done anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Tudeschizieuinchid, for Links you provided, I finally understand that I have to spend a week to learn or understand ADO.NET (your provided links will make it fast)

Answer (score 3):

ADO.NET works the way it works so you should forget the comparisons to ADO, which are irrelevant, and just learn that. If you want to retrieve, use and save data then you use a data adapter and a `DataTable`, which may or may not be part of a `DataSet`.

You call `Fill` on the adapter and that will execute the `SelectCommand` to populate the specified `DataTable`. When you want to save changes, you call `Update` on the adapter and that will execute the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` as needed for each `DataRow`. You can generate those commands yourself or, assuming that the original query involves a single database table and includes the primary key, you can use a command builder to generate them for you. You can check out some of my own examples [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

The presentation and the data access are two separate things, so your controls are irrelevant to the data access. You can bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to your controls and, if desired, associate it with a `BindingNavigator` for navigation. Data binding will take care of moving data between the data source and the UI and back again.

If you like, you can generate a typed `DataSet` as part of your project. That will create a number of types specific to your data, so you get better Intellisense and type safety as well as not having to create any commands yourself. In that case, you will use table adapters instead of data adapters. You still call `Fill` and `Update` though, so the general structure of your code doesn't change.

Comment: Yes I have to learn, and thank you for your examples, which will make my learning easy and fast. Thank You. @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 3):

I come from a long time Access/VB background.

A few things:

Just like VB5/VB6 had some "data binding" controls and systems?

That "choice" to use automatic databinding STILL exists in VB.net. What that means is you can build a form, have record navigation, and not have to write any code. So, add new, save a record, delete, and edit controls on the form can all be automated if you wish.

But, like VB5/VB6, often was the case that we want to write the code to do this, and we don't want some "automatic" or perhaps better said "auto magic" system that does all this work for you.

So, let's do a few examples using a datatable. In vb.net, a datatable is VERY much like a recordset from ADO. The major advantages is that this recordset choice is nice, since it can work with just about any database - SQL server, oracle, or in this case ms-access.

However, before we post/write some code?

The FIRST thing we need to deal with is the x32 vs x64 bit issue.

In the base, Visual C++, Visual Basic etc., and even ms-access were all x32 bits. Kind of made life simple!

But, in the last dozen years, all OS and most developer tools have made the jump to x64 bit land. Most interesting is that .net is REALLY cool in that in near EVERY case, it don't care if your software is x32 bits, or x64 bits. .net has this amazing ability to run as x32 bits, or x64 bits.

HOWEVER, and a BIG however: when you use .net to connect to and work with a non .net system, say like ms-access files? Well the you ALSO using the database engine from ms-access. And that is not .net code, so NOW the issue of x32 vs x64 bits matters VERY much.

While not a complex issue - it is an issue you MUST resolve and deal with before writing any code.

Next up:

If you using vs2022 or not. If you are using a previous version of VS, then that product was always a x32 bit product. Now, finally, vs2022 is the FIRST version of VS that is x64 bit product. While VS has been x32 bits almost forever?

It was able to compile + create x64 bit code - but we talking about .net code and that "cool" feature to run as x32 or x64 bits.

however, WHAT and HOW your vb.net code runs matters here. To make a long story short, you need to set (force) your project to run as the correct bit size to use + consume + talk to the Access data engine.

So, you need to know if you are running ms-access x32, or ms-access x64. (there are 2 versions of Office now - been that way for 13 years!).

So, first order of the day is to set/force/make sure your vb.net project is set to the bit size that matches the version of the JET (access) data engine you are using.

And there is a "new" version of that VERY long time JET data engine (the one that access uses). It is now called ACE, and there is a x32 bit version, and a x64 bit version (2 versions are required, since unlike .net "magic" ability to run x32 or as x64, office and the Access data engine don't have that magic ability. If using older access and mdb files, that is only x32. If you need/want to open/use accDB files, then you MUST use ACE (the newer version of the JET data engine that access uses).

So, first up, your project setting, assuming say office x32 bits, then we force our project to run as x32 bits.

And if you don't see/have an x32 config, then make one.

I'm going to do this in this example:

So, the CPU setting drop down did not have a x86 (x32) setting, so I added one. Note the easy steps to do this. In pre vs2022 days, you MIGHT get away not bother, and using ANY cpu. However WHEN working with ms-access and the JET (or now ACE data engine), then you MUST deal with this issue.

OK, so now that we have the project setup to run as x32 (x86) bits, the next step is to create a connection to the access database.

This can be (should be) done in your project settings. (not like we going to type connection strings over and over in code, are we?).

So, let's set up a connection.

Use "application" setting, not user.

And do NOT forget to hit "advanced" tab to select the correct version of the Access data engine (JET for mdb, and ACE for accdb - ACE must be used if your using Access/ACE x64 and that means a accDB file only).

So, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, it would take a LONG description here, but in above you see a test connection button. if you are using vs2022, and Access x32, that test connection button WILL always fail, but when  you run the code, it will work.

OK, so now we have a connection set up. So, now back to our data table.

About the ONLY extra thing a ma do when using a .net data table, is in the old days, you have the recordset + a connection.

In .net, you have a data table (like a recordset), and you have a connection (very much like before). However, we ALSO have a 3rd new thing (issue) to deal with, and that is the data adaptor. In fact, to get/grab/use data, you do NOT need the data adaptor. And in fact it means exactly what it means (to adapt data - which means to write back to the database).

So, let's now say we have simple form, and some controls on that form. And for this example, we will NOT use the auto-magic data binding systems that VB6 or vb.net has (but do keep in mind you CAN use data bound controls, and thus similar to ms-access, you don't have to write much of any of this code).

So, we hand coding this, and it for sure a great way to learn.

So, say a few controls on the form, like this:

[image]

For this example, I have a load button. I would think in a real application, we would have some type of grid or search screen and pick a row we display and then JUMP to this edit page. But, let's keep this simple.

So, in above, I can type in a record id (ID, PK number), and then hit load button.

So, that code looks like this:

```
Dim rstData As DataTable
Private Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLoad.Click

    Dim strSQL As String =
        $"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = {txtID.Text}"

    rstData = MyRst(strSQL)
    LoadForm()

End Sub

Sub LoadForm()

    With rstData.Rows(0)

        txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName").ToString()
        txtFirst.Text = .Item("FirstName").ToString()
        txtLast.Text = .Item("LastName").ToString()
        txtCity.Text = .Item("City").ToString()
        txtProvince.Text = .Item("Province").ToString()
        chkActive.Checked = .Item("Active")
        txtDescription.Text = .Item("Description").ToString()

    End With

End Sub
```

Nothing really special.

Note how I stated to load/get/grab data, we ONLY need a data table, and a connection. (just like the old days of ADO!).

But, I get rather tired - about the 1st day of coding typing over and over such connection string and pull data code. So, in above, I used a helper routine (myRST). Not required, but with this little helper routine, then I feel VERY much like I am working in say access or vb of long ago.

That helper routine was this:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

In fact, above is so handy, you would do well to place the above routine in say a global module of "helper" code.

Note in above, how we ONLY have a data table, and a connection. We also did use a command object. It turns out you have "quite a few" combinations of choosing which objects to use, but the above should suffice.

So, we pull the one record. The screen will now look like this:

[image]

So, really now, all we need is our save code.

We have to send the data table BACK to the database. They are disconnected, and this can often mean a bit more work, but again, build just 2 or 3 helper routines, and your be right back to coding speed compared to those old yesterdays.

So, to send back data, we have to use that data adaptor (remember, you ONLY really need an "adaptor" WHEN you going to do write operations. As the data pull shows, we did not care nor need nor use some "data adaptor", since we were just pulling data.

So, the save button will have to

Pull values from controls back into our data row.

Write out the data row back to the database.

So, our save button code is thus this;

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    SaveForm()

End Sub

Sub SaveForm()

    With rstData.Rows(0)

        .Item("HotelName") = txtHotel.Text
        .Item("FirstName") = txtFirst.Text
        .Item("LastName") = txtLast.Text
        .Item("City") = txtCity.Text
        .Item("Province") = txtProvince.Text
        .Item("Active") = chkActive.Checked
        .Item("Description") = txtDescription.Text

    End With

    'send data back to database

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, the "extra" step here is using the command builder, and the "adapt".

In fact, I made a helper routine in which I can pass JUST the data table, the table name, and then once again, I don't have to write that code over and over.

Now, while ms-access is somewhat protected against SQL injections?

I would consider also adding this routine:

```
Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As OleDbCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, in place of a raw SQL string, we should consider using a SQL command object (since it contains a connection, and reader all in one object). And this means one could ALWAYS use parameter in code, and  NEVER use concentration to build your SQL. So, this code to load would be considered better, and SQL injection safe:

So, to prevent me from being burned at the stake here, I do recommend that you try and avoid in-line SQL that uses concatenation in code - it is now considered a very bad coding practice, where as when I started out years ago, it was not much of a issue.

So now this code is considered a better approach:

```
Private Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLoad.Click

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
        OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtID.Text


    rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    LoadForm()

End Sub
```

In fact often I do like using parameter's, since then messy SQL with extra quotes, comma etc. does not occur, and those types of bugs in SQL are always quite nasty to find or even fix.

So, in theory, all we really need to do here is build 3 helper routines, and we will wind up with LESS and cleaner code then what we had in the old days of ADO.

So, in our global module, we can add MyRstSave routine, and thus the code in the form becomes VERY clean, as we only would need the data table object (rstData), and the cmdSQL object.

So, MyrstSave could be this:

```
Public Sub MyRstSave(rstData As DataTable, strTable As String)

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM {strTable}", conn)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, now our whole code in the form becomes this:

```
Dim rstData As DataTable

Private Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLoad.Click

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
        OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtID.Text
    rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    LoadForm()

End Sub

Sub LoadForm()

    With rstData.Rows(0)

        txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName").ToString()
        txtFirst.Text = .Item("FirstName").ToString()
        txtLast.Text = .Item("LastName").ToString()
        txtCity.Text = .Item("City").ToString()
        txtProvince.Text = .Item("Province").ToString()
        chkActive.Checked = .Item("Active")
        txtDescription.Text = .Item("Description").ToString()

    End With

End Sub


Sub SaveForm()

    With rstData.Rows(0)

        .Item("HotelName") = txtHotel.Text
        .Item("FirstName") = txtFirst.Text
        .Item("LastName") = txtLast.Text
        .Item("City") = txtCity.Text
        .Item("Province") = txtProvince.Text
        .Item("Active") = chkActive.Checked
        .Item("Description") = txtDescription.Text

    End With

    'send data back to database

    MyRstSave(rstData, "tblHotelsA")

End Sub
```

So, with above, I think we quite much writing a wee bit less code then old style ado code, and we don't even bother with connection string stuff in that form code module at all. The above is actually quite clean code, and not at all messy.

So, with 2-3 helper routines, then read of data, and writing of data becomes no more work or efforts then what old ADO forced one to do here.

Last but not least:

Like VB6, there are data adaptors that you can drop into a form, and automatic data binding can be done, and thus edit, delete and save of data back to the database can be done with data bound controls, but for now, the above should suffice, and as you can see, the code approach is not really much different then what you done in the past.

Comment: yes indeed, and this is MUCH why I am writing back to the database using a data table, since then the column names and values can't get messed up.  The "avoiding" of parameter's in this post to write data back was thus quite much done by intention. Using a data table with ms-access thus much allows one to avoid sql parameter's for a update or insert due to the parameter issue you note.

Comment: Thank you @Albert D. Kallal for your insight knowledge and direct examples. I instant learnt that DATATABLE can work independently, There is no need to use DATASET.

Comment: one more favor please, is parameterized query more reliable to use than DATATABLE with DATAADAPTER.COMMANDBUILDER

Comment: No difference, but cmdBuilder is good choice. The reason is that while I used a nice named parameter in this example, if you have/use more then 1 paramotor when use JET/ACE, then the ORDER of the parameter's you add have must match the order of them in the sql. For pulling the ID, we want SQL injection safe code (any user inputs). For update then we would have "lots" of parameters and thus cmdBuilder is probably better since then order does not matter. And tends to be less code anyway. I mean, you could write out a update command - but that's prone to more code errors then this example..

Comment: And furthermore, we were attempting to give "similar" code to past practice which should make one feel more at home.  So, when dealing with lots of columns? Espeically for a update of a row, then I do suggest this is not only less code, but also requires much less messy in-line SQL for that update (in fact we did't have to write the update command, did we? So, for any case to pull a record with input value - especially user input value, then you can't use command builder anyway, can you? However, for the row update, then yes, I do suggest command builder.

Comment: So I can't say command builder is more reliable, but it certainly going to be less prone to the developer making code errors in both not having to write the SQL update command, and also not messing up the order of parameter's. So, I do suggest suggest that this approach is less error prone for doing updates, and I suppose then some would from that suggest that is more reliable. I don't think it is more reliable, but it is certainly less error prone from a coder's point of view.  I mean, if you updating 10 columns our of 40, then that update command was less messy, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use a dataset in place of a datatable, but I see VERY little reason to do so. Datasets are simple an array() of tables, and unless one needs more then one table, then I see no reason to use a dataset. For some VERY strange reason, many code examples use a dataset when they only have one table and I think that is poor examples. Using a dataset object when you only have one table don't make sense. However datasets are often required when importing XML since xml can represent more then one table, and SOME of the xml import routines require a dataset even with 1 table in xml.