How to use a VB.NET form and SQL to insert information into a database?
I am super new to programming. I am working on a personal project creating a student attendance system. I am using Visual Studio and SQL Server. I have my server connected to Visual Studio and also the database I am going to be using. I created the table where I want to insert information from the form.
But I am struggling to actually get the correct code to make that insert happen. Please advise.
Here is my form:

Here is the code I tried.
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=TECH-TAYNE;Initial Catalog=StudentAttendanceDB;Integrated Security=True;")

    Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, DbCommand As SqlCommand)
        Dim StudentId As Integer = studentIdTextBox.Text
        Dim StudentName As String = studentNmeTextBox.Text
        Dim RollCall As String = rollCallTextBox.Text
        Dim Status As String = statusTextBox.Text
    
        Dim Query As String = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[studentInfo]"
        DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        DbCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudentId", StudentId))
        DbCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudentName", StudentName))
        DbCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RollCall", RollCall))
        DbCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Status", Status))
        connection.Open()   

        DbCommand.ExecuteReader.Close()
        connection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved Successfully")   

    End Sub

I was expecting it to insert information into the database. I did not get an error message but it did not do anything I expected it to.
Please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I understand this code might be all messed up since I am new to it.
The new Code I tried that did resolve my issue.
Public Class Form1
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim index As Integer
Private Sub form1_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=TECH-TAYNE;Initial Catalog=StudentAttendanceDB;Integrated Security=True;")
        Dim command As SqlCommand()
        connection.Open()

        table.Columns.Add("StudentId", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

        table.Columns.Add("StudentName", Type.GetType("System.String"))

        table.Columns.Add("RollCall", Type.GetType("System.String"))

        table.Columns.Add("Status", Type.GetType("System.String"))


        DataGridView1.DataSource = table


        connection.Close()

    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
    table.Rows.Add(studentIdTextBox.Text, studentNmeTextBox.Text, rollCallTextBox.Text, statusTextBox.Text)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    index = e.RowIndex

    Dim selectedrow As DataGridViewRow

    selectedrow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)

    studentIdTextBox.Text = selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

    studentNmeTextBox.Text = selectedrow.Cells(1).Value.ToString

    rollCallTextBox.Text = selectedrow.Cells(2).Value.ToString

    statusTextBox.Text = selectedrow.Cells(3).Value.ToString




End Sub

End Classenter image description here

Why the ButtonSave_Click has a parameter DbCommand? Can you show the code where you call the method? Apart from that your sql is incorrect. It should be like INSERT INTO [dbo].[studentInfo] (StudentId,StudentName,RollCall,Status) VALUES (@StudentId,@StudentName,@RollCall,@Status). So your sql parameters must be contained in the sql query.

The following may be of interest: Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET and Modifying Data with a DbDataAdapter

Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346467/classic-ado-recordset-alternative-in-ado-net

The Click event handler has sender As Object and e As EventArgs parameters, but where does the third parameter DbCommand As SqlCommand come from? I never saw such an event handler before. Also, your Query string (which is wrong as others have pointed out) is never assigned to the command.

Incidentally, you should create the SQL connection, use it, then dispose of it as soon as it is finished with, in the fashion shown in this documentation. (You may need to select "VB" instead of "C#" in the dropdown near the top-right.)

@user246821 none of my code was written from AI i am a first year student so my coding knowledge is very limited which is why i came to a site with people who have way more knowledge and understanding than me. Thank you for responding to my question though.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355687/10024425, but you'll write must less code if you use the methods described in my previous URLs.

@user246821 i was able to figure it out from a youtube video. This is the code that worked.

The following may be of interest: EditedFormattedValue and FormattedValue
