System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get returned Nothing
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
Dim enter As New Apptfm

    ' Ensure a row is selected in the DataGridView
    If enter.DataGridView1.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Retrieve the primary key or unique identifier for the record to update
        Dim id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(enter.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("CID").Value)
    
        Dim connectionString As String = "Server=IT-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Appointments; Integrated Security=true"
        Dim query As String = "UPDATE Customers SET [Plate No.] = @plateno, [Cond No.] = @condno, Customer = @customer, [Cellphone No.] = @cpno, [Tel No.] = @telno, [Unit Model] = @unit, [Job Type] = @jobtype, [S.A.] = @sa, [KMS Reading] = @kms, Remarks = @remarks WHERE CID = @id"
    
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
                ' Add parameters
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plateno", PNtxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condno", CStxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer", CNtxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpno", CPtxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telno", TPtxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", UMcbx.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobtype", JTcbx.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sa", SAcbx.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kms", KMStxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", RemarksBtn.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id) ' Add the unique identifier parameter
    
                connection.Open()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If rowsAffected > 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Save Successfully!")
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Didn't Save!")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No row selected in DataGridView!")
    End If

End Sub

It says that Dim id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(enter.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("CID").Value) is null and not getting any value Apptfm DataGridView1, did I miss some kind of method??

Step through with the debugger and see what the contents of CurrentRow are. That should give you a good hint. Its clear though that the issue is unrelated to SQL Server, hence I have removed the tag.

You have just declared enter at the top of your SaveBtn_Click. If there is no code that populates the datagridview's datasource in your form's (Apptfm) New event, then of course it will have no rows.

If the code above is part of the class Apptfm (a form class) then you refer to the current instance with the keyword Me (as in Me.DataGridView1.... etc) or you omit it entirely. Also remember to check always if the CurrentRow is a NewRow before attempting to retrieve values from it

Just so you know: AddWithValue is Evil, AddWithValue is evil!, and Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349235/10024425, Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET, and DataAdapters and DataReaders

The following may be of interest: EditedFormattedValue and FormattedValue
